# Person A is online and sends a message to person B; person B is offline but opens the message, is "seen" still displayed to person A?

Tags: facebook, chat, facebook-messenger

Person A sends a message via chat or just normal private messaging on to person B..

Person B opens the message in there private message area, but is offline on facebook chat..

***Questions***

1. Does person A still receive the "seen" notification that there message has been seen?
2. If person B just clicks the envelope icon on the top bar at facebook to preview the message but doesn't open it is the "seen" notification still displayed to person A?

Answer (score 3):

Opening the "Preview" (Chat icon in the top bar) does not trigger the read receipt, neither does going to `facebook.com/messages/`. But opening the conversation (`facebook.com/messages/?action=read&tid=id.123456789`) by clicking on the message or opening the chat window sets the "seen" flag and Person A will see it although B is offline.

Source: Just tested